# problema con signo + en string javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap

me ha surgido un problema en javascript y bootstrap que no se como solventar, espero me puedan ayudar, la cuestion es que tengo una funcion de javascript que recoge valores hace una cadena y envia esa cadena a un modal de boot strap el problema viene que cuando pongo el signo "+" desaparece y todo lo que escribo despues de el tambien o cambia el "+" por un espacio. escaparia el caracter pero como no es una cadena fija no se como hacerlo.

Este es mi codigo:

```
function aceptar2(){
          var codigo=document.getElementById("codigo").value;
          var codfam=document.getElementById("codfam").value;
          var cantidad=document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
          var precio=document.getElementById("prec").value;
          var importe=document.getElementById("imp").value;
          var descrip=document.getElementById("descrip").value;
          var dcto=document.getElementById("dcto").value;

          var cadena="&serie=<?php echo $serie; ?>&codigo="+codigo+"&codfam="+codfam+"&cantidad="+cantidad+"&prec="+prec+"&imp="+imp+"&descrip="+descrip+"&dcto="+dcto+"&modificado=1";
                   
        document.getElementById("frame_datos").src="modifica.php?numdocumentotmp=<?php echo $numdocumentotmp; ?>&num=<?php echo $num; ?>"+cadena;
        cancelar2();  
      }
```

lo que hace es recoger los datos de un formulario y enviarlos a una pagina php que los procesa y los incluye en una BD, y donde quiero escapar los signos es en `descrip` el cual puede contener cosas distintas cada vez.

Comment: ¿Todas las variables tienen su texto correspondiente? ¿La consola te da algún error al ejecutar la función?

Comment: si todas las variables tienen su texto correspondiente y la funcion funciona correctamente unicamente se "come" el signo "+" y a veces se come el texto despues del signo + si no lo pongo funciona sin problemas, he probado con otros signos y caracteres especiales y funciona bien solo me pasa con el +

Comment: Con template strings te ocurre lo mismo? https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: sigues fallando con template strings

Comment: Pues lo único más que me chirría es el php dentro del JS

Comment: sin embargo eso funciona correctamente XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque no tenia mucha esperanza con que funcionase intente hacer un `replace()` de javascript y mágicamente me funciono. He de decir que el error no era de javascript sino de que al pasar la cadena a un src este necesitaba que fuese un caracter url [dejo aqui el enlace de los caracteres url](https://zainex.es/guia-rapida/html/html-url-encode-codificacion)

```
function aceptar2(){
          var codigo=document.getElementById("codigo").value;
          var codfam=document.getElementById("codfam").value;
          var cantidad=document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
          var precio=document.getElementById("prec").value;
          var importe=document.getElementById("imp").value;
          var descrip=document.getElementById("descrip").value;
          var dcto=document.getElementById("dcto").value;
         
          var describien = descrip.replace(/[+]/gi,'%2b');

          var cadena="&serie=<?php echo $serie; ?>&codigo="+codigo+"&codfam="+codfam+"&cantidad="+cantidad+"&prec="+prec+"&imp="+imp+"&descrip="+describien+"&dcto="+dcto+"&modificado=1";
                   
        document.getElementById("frame_datos").src="modifica.php?numdocumentotmp=<?php echo $numdocumentotmp; ?>&num=<?php echo $num; ?>"+cadena;
        cancelar2();  
      }
```

Gracias por la ayuda prestada, espero que le pueda servir a otros esta pregunta.

Comment: @Excorpion perdón que estaba editando la respuesta que llevaba a confusión, lo que me pasaba a mi realmente era que los navegadores interpretan el + como un espacio en su barra URL de ahí que al pasarlo en un src se lo comiese.

Comment: En lugar de crear un parche para remplazar solo un caracter, puedes usar `encodeURIComponent()` para que cualquier caracter pueda ser enviado por URL.